# Enigma Implementation by Python newbie

Tags: python, beginner, cryptography

I want to learn Python, so I ported a C# Enigma implementation of mine. It got UnitTests and is running.

I'm looking for a review, telling me, where I don't know best practices, where I break naming conventions, where I look like a C# programmer writing Python:-)

Thanks & have fun Harry

https://github.com/HaraldLeitner/Enigma
BusinessLogic.py

```
from Enums import Mode


class BusinessLogic:
    def __init__(self, rolls):
        self._rolls = rolls
        self._rolls_reverse = rolls.copy()
        self._rolls_reverse.reverse()

    def transform_file(self, infile, outfile, mode):
        buffer_size = 65536

        in_file = open(infile, 'rb', buffer_size)
        out_file = open(outfile, 'wb', buffer_size)

        buffer = bytearray(in_file.read(buffer_size))

        while len(buffer):
            self.transform_buffer(buffer, mode)
            out_file.write(buffer)
            buffer = bytearray(in_file.read(buffer_size))

        in_file.close()
        out_file.close()

    def transform_buffer(self, buffer, mode):
        if mode == Mode.ENC:
            for i in range(len(buffer)):
                for roll in self._rolls:
                    roll.encrypt(buffer, i)
                self.roll_on()

        if mode == Mode.DEC:
            for i in range(len(buffer)):
                for roll in self._rolls_reverse:
                    roll.decrypt(buffer, i)
                self.roll_on()

    def roll_on(self):
        for roll in self._rolls:
            if not roll.roll_on():
                break
```

Enums.py

```
from enum import Enum


class Mode(Enum):
    ENC = 0
    DEC = 1
```

Roll.py

```
class Roll:

    def __init__(self, transitions, turn_over_indices):
        self._transitions = transitions
        self._turn_over_indices = turn_over_indices
        self._re_transitions = bytearray(256)

        for x in self._transitions:
            self._re_transitions[self._transitions[x]] = x

        self._position = 0

    def check_input(self, turnover_indices_count):
        if len(self._transitions) != 256:
            raise ValueError("Wrong Transition length ")

        for i in range(256):
            found = 0
            for j in self._transitions:
                if self._transitions[j] == i:
                    found = 1
                    continue

            if not found:
                raise ValueError("Transitions not 1-1 complete")

        if len(self._turn_over_indices) != turnover_indices_count:
            raise ValueError("Wrong TurnOverIndices length ")

        for i in range(len(self._turn_over_indices) - 1):
            if self._turn_over_indices[i] == self._turn_over_indices[i + 1]:
                raise ValueError("turn_over_indices has doubles")

    def encrypt(self, buffer, index):
        buffer[index] = self._transitions[(buffer[index] + self._position) & 0xff]

    def decrypt(self, buffer, index):
        buffer[index] = (self._re_transitions[int(buffer[index])] - self._position) & 0xff

    def roll_on(self):
        self._position = (self._position + 1) & 0xff
        return self._turn_over_indices.count(self._position)
```

Enigma.ini

```
[DEFAULT]
TransitionCount = 53
```

Main.py

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os
import sys
from random import random, randbytes, randint
from time import sleep

from BusinessLogic import BusinessLogic
from Enums import Mode
from Roll import Roll


class Program:
    def __init__(self, transition_count=0):
        self._mode = None
        self._rolls = []
        self._inputFilename = None
        self._keyFilename = None
        self._transitionCount = None
        config = ConfigParser()
        config.read("enigma.ini")
        if transition_count < 1:
            self._transitionCount = config.getint("DEFAULT", "TransitionCount")
        else:
            self._transitionCount = transition_count

    def main(self):
        if len(sys.argv) != 4:
            print("Generate key with 'keygen x key.file' where x > 3 is the number of rolls.")
            print("Encrypt a file with 'enc a.txt key.file'")
            print("Decrypt a file with 'dec a.txt key.file'")
            exit(1)

        self.run_main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])

    def run_main(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):

        self._keyFilename = arg3

        if arg1 == "keygen":
            self.keygen(int(arg2))
            return

        self._inputFilename = arg2

        if arg1.lower() == 'enc':
            self._mode = Mode.ENC
        elif arg1 == 'dec':
            self._mode = Mode.DEC
        else:
            raise Exception("Undefined Encryption Mode.")

        self.create_rolls()
        BusinessLogic(self._rolls).transform_file(self._inputFilename, self._inputFilename + '.' + self._mode.name,
                                                  self._mode)

    def keygen(self, roll_count):
        if roll_count < 4:
            raise Exception("Not enough rolls.")

        if os.path.exists(self._keyFilename):
            os.remove(self._keyFilename)

        key = bytearray()

        for i in range(roll_count):
            transform = bytearray(256)
            for j in range(256):
                transform[j] = j

            while not self.is_twisted(transform):
                for j in range(256):
                    rand1 = randint(0, 255)
                    rand2 = randint(0, 255)

                    temp = transform[rand1]
                    transform[rand1] = transform[rand2]
                    transform[rand2] = temp

            key += transform

            transitions = bytearray()
            while len(transitions) < self._transitionCount:
                rand = randint(0, 255)
                if not transitions.count(rand):
                    transitions.append(rand)

            key += transitions

        file = open(self._keyFilename, 'wb')
        file.write(key)
        file.close()

        print("Keys generated.")
        sleep(1)

    def is_twisted(self, trans):
        for i in range(256):
            if trans[i] == i:
                return 0

        return 1

    def create_rolls(self):
        roll_key_length = 256 + self._transitionCount
        file = open(self._keyFilename, 'rb')
        key = file.read()
        file.close()

        if len(key) % roll_key_length:
            raise Exception('Invalid key_size')

        roll_count = int(len(key) / roll_key_length)

        for rollNumber in range(roll_count):
            self._rolls.append(Roll(key[rollNumber * roll_key_length: rollNumber * roll_key_length + 256],
                                    key[
                                    rollNumber * roll_key_length + 256: rollNumber * roll_key_length + 256 + self._transitionCount]))

        for roll in self._rolls:
            roll.check_input(self._transitionCount)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Program().main()
```

UnitTest.py

````
import os
import unittest

from BusinessLogic import BusinessLogic
from Enums import Mode
from Roll import Roll
from main import Program


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.trans_linear = bytearray(256)  # here every char is mapped to itself
        self.trans_linear_invert = bytearray(256)  # match the first to the last etc
        self.trans_shift_1 = bytearray(256)  # 'a' is mapped to 'b' etc
        self.trans_shift_2 = bytearray(256)  # 'a' is mapped to 'c' etc

        self.businesslogic_encode = None
        self.businesslogic_decode = None

        self.encrypted_message = bytearray()
        self.decrypted_message = bytearray()

        self.init_test_rolls()

    def init_test_rolls(self):
        for i in range(256):
            self.trans_linear[i] = i
            self.trans_linear_invert[i] = 255 - i
            self.trans_shift_1[i] = (i + 1) % 256
            self.trans_shift_2[i] = (i + 2) % 256

    def init_business_logic(self, transitions, turnovers):
        rolls_encrypt = []
        rolls_decrypt = []

        for index in range(len(transitions)):
            rolls_encrypt.append(Roll(transitions[index], turnovers[index]))
            rolls_decrypt.append(Roll(transitions[index], turnovers[index]))

        self.businesslogic_encode = BusinessLogic(rolls_encrypt)
        self.businesslogic_decode = BusinessLogic(rolls_decrypt)

    def crypt(self, msg):
        self.encrypted_message = bytearray(msg)
        self.businesslogic_encode.transform_buffer(self.encrypted_message, Mode.ENC)
        self.decrypted_message = bytearray(self.encrypted_message)
        self.businesslogic_decode.transform_buffer(self.decrypted_message, Mode.DEC)

    def test_one_byte_one_roll_linear(self):
        for i in range(256):
            self.init_business_logic([self.trans_linear], [[0]])
            self.crypt([i])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.encrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.decrypted_message[0])

    def test_one_byte_one_roll_shift_one(self):
        for i in range(256):
            self.init_business_logic([self.trans_shift_1], [[0]])
            self.crypt([i])
            self.assertEqual((i + 1) % 256, self.encrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.decrypted_message[0])

    def test_one_byte_one_roll_shift_two(self):
        for i in range(256):
            self.init_business_logic([self.trans_shift_2], [[0]])
            self.crypt([i])
            self.assertEqual((i + 2) % 256, self.encrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.decrypted_message[0])

    def test_two_byte_one_roll_linear(self):
        for i in range(256):
            self.init_business_logic([self.trans_linear], [[0]])
            self.crypt([i, (i + 1) % 256])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.encrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual((i + 2) % 256, self.encrypted_message[1])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.decrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual((i + 1) % 256, self.decrypted_message[1])

    def test_two_byte_one_roll_shift1(self):
        for i in range(256):
            self.init_business_logic([self.trans_shift_1], [[0]])
            self.crypt([i, (i + 1) % 256])
            self.assertEqual((i + 1) % 256, self.encrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual((i + 3) % 256, self.encrypted_message[1])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.decrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual((i + 1) % 256, self.decrypted_message[1])

    def test_two_byte_one_roll_invert(self):
        for i in range(256):
            self.init_business_logic([self.trans_linear_invert], [[0]])
            self.crypt([i, i])
            self.assertEqual(255 - i, self.encrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual((256 + 255 - i - 1) & 0xff, self.encrypted_message[1])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.decrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.decrypted_message[1])

    def test_two_byte_two_roll_linear(self):
        for i in range(256):
            self.init_business_logic([self.trans_linear, self.trans_linear], [[0], [0]])
            self.crypt([i, (i + 1) & 0xff])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.encrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual((i + 2) & 0xff, self.encrypted_message[1])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.decrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual((i + 1) & 0xff, self.decrypted_message[1])

    def test_two_byte_two_roll_shift1(self):
        for i in range(256):
            self.init_business_logic([self.trans_shift_1, self.trans_shift_1], [[0], [0]])
            self.crypt([i, (i + 1) & 0xff])
            self.assertEqual((i + 2) & 0xff, self.encrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual((i + 4) & 0xff, self.encrypted_message[1])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.decrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual((i + 1) & 0xff, self.decrypted_message[1])

    def test_two_byte_two_roll_shift2(self):
        self.init_business_logic([self.trans_shift_2, self.trans_shift_2], [[0], [0]])
        self.crypt([7, 107])
        self.assertEqual(11, self.encrypted_message[0])
        self.assertEqual(112, self.encrypted_message[1])
        self.assertEqual(7, self.decrypted_message[0])
        self.assertEqual(107, self.decrypted_message[1])

    def test_two_byte_two_roll_invert(self):
        for i in range(256):
            self.init_business_logic([self.trans_linear_invert, self.trans_linear_invert], [[0], [0]])
            self.crypt([i, (i + 1) & 0xff])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.encrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual((i + 2) & 0xff, self.encrypted_message[1])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.decrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual((i + 1) & 0xff, self.decrypted_message[1])

    def test_three_byte_two_roll_turnover(self):
        for i in range(256):
            self.init_business_logic([self.trans_linear, self.trans_linear], [range(256), range(256)])
            self.crypt([i, (i + 1) & 0xff, (i + 2) & 0xff])
            self.assertEqual(i, self.encrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual((i + 3) & 0xff, self.encrypted_message[1])
            self.assertEqual((i + 6) & 0xff, self.encrypted_message[2])

            self.assertEqual(i, self.decrypted_message[0])
            self.assertEqual((i + 1) & 0xff, self.decrypted_message[1])
            self.assertEqual((i + 2) & 0xff, self.decrypted_message[2])

    def test_three_byte_two_different_roll_turnover(self):
        self.init_business_logic([self.trans_linear, self.trans_shift_1], [range(4), range(4)])
        self.crypt([7, 107])
        self.assertEqual(8, self.encrypted_message[0])
        self.assertEqual(110, self.encrypted_message[1])

        self.assertEqual(7, self.decrypted_message[0])
        self.assertEqual(107, self.decrypted_message[1])

    def test_three_byte_two_different_roll_turnover3(self):
        self.init_business_logic([self.trans_linear, self.trans_linear_invert], [range(4), range(4)])
        self.crypt([7, 107])
        self.assertEqual(248, self.encrypted_message[0])
        self.assertEqual(146, self.encrypted_message[1])

        self.assertEqual(7, self.decrypted_message[0])
        self.assertEqual(107, self.decrypted_message[1])

    def test_real_live(self):
        msg_size = 65536
        msg = bytearray(msg_size)
        for i in range(msg_size):
            msg[i] = i & 0xff

        self.init_business_logic([self.trans_linear, self.trans_linear_invert, self.trans_shift_1, self.trans_shift_2],
                                 [[0, 22, 44, 100], [11, 44, 122, 200], [33, 77, 99, 222], [55, 67, 79, 240]])

        self.crypt(msg)
        for i in range(msg_size):
            self.assertEqual(msg[i], self.decrypted_message[i])

    def test_integration(self):
        key_file_name = "any.key"
        msg_file_name = "msg.file"

        msg_size = 65536 * 5
        msg = bytearray(msg_size)
        for i in range(msg_size):
            msg[i] = i & 0xff

        if os.path.exists(msg_file_name):
            os.remove(msg_file_name)

        file = open(msg_file_name, 'wb')
        file.write(msg)
        file.close()

        program = Program(55)
        program.run_main("keygen", 5, key_file_name)
        program.run_main("enc", msg_file_name, key_file_name)
        program2 = Program(55)
        program2.run_main("dec", msg_file_name + ".enc", key_file_name)

        file = open(msg_file_name + ".enc.dec", 'rb')
        decypted = file.read()
        file.close()

        for i in range(msg_size):
            self.assertEqual(msg[i], decypted[i])

        self.assertEqual(msg_size, len(decypted))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```
````

Answer (score 4):

First, a warm welcome to the python language! None of this is in any particular order.

## `argparse`

There is a really nice argument parsing library available out of the box which makes parsing command line args much less clunky. I'd set up your parser like this:

```py
# Maybe put this into cli.py
from argparse import ArgumentParser


def setup_parser():
    parser = ArgumentParser(desc="Enigma written in python")
    parser.add_argument("mode", type=str, choices=['enc', 'dec', 'keygen'], help="Encode, Decode, or generate key")
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input-file", dest="input_file", type=str, help="File to be encrypted/decrypted")
    parser.add_argument("key_file", type=str, help="Key file to be generated or to be used to encode/decode")
    return parser


parser = setup_parser()
```

Then your arguments can be used like:

```py
args = parser.parse_args()

args.mode
'enc'

args.key_file
'mykey.rsa'

args.input_file
'to_be_encrypted.txt'
```

## Variable Names

To go along with the argparse suggestion, variables should be given descriptive names. In `run_main`, you have names like `arg<i>`, which make reading and debugging the code a little tricky. Name them how you intend to use them:

```py
def main(mode, key_file, input_file=None, num_rolls=0):
    ...
```

Variable names and function names are recommended to be `snake_case`, where classes are recommended to be `PascalCase`. The Style Guide (also known as PEP-8) can be found [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Note however, that it's a guide. You don't *have* to follow it at every step, but it will make your code look nicer most of the time.

## Enums and type-checking

Enums do a nice job of handling type-checking for you. You can re-define your enum like this:

```py
class Mode(Enum):
    ENC = 'enc'
    DEC = 'dec'
```

Then, not only will the argument parser catch an invalid enum entry, so will the class:

```py
mode = Mode('enc')
mode is Mode.ENC
True

mode = Mode('dec')
mode is Mode.DEC
True

mode = Mode('bad')
TypeError:
    'bad' is not a valid Mode
```

## Creating `rolls`

There are a few ways to clean this code up. First, I think defining your slice points outside of the slice notation itself on the key is a bit easier to read:

```py
    ~snip~
    for roll_number in range(roll_count):
        # For readability, I would just compute these values here. It
        # makes the slices look better
        start = roll_number * roll_key_length
        middle = roll_number * roll_key_length + 256
        end = roll_number * roll_key_length + 256 + transition_count

        # now it's easier to see what the key slices are
        roll = Roll(key[start:middle], key[middle:end]))
```

Second, you iterate over all of your rolls twice, when you don't need to. Just do the check during the iteration:

```py
    for roll_number in range(roll_count):
        ~snip~

        roll.check_input(transition_count)

        rolls.append(roll)
```

### File Handling

It's better practice to open files using the context manager `with`, as it will automatically close the file handle for you when you are done using it, no matter what happens:

```py
# go from this
fh = open(myfile, 'rb')
content = fh.read()
fh.close()

# to this
with open(myfile, 'rb') as fh:
    content = fh.read()


# and to open multiple files:
with open('file1.txt') as fh1, open('file2.txt') as fh2, ..., open('fileN.txt') as fhN:
    # do things
```

There is also a spot in your code where you remove a file, do some calculations, and then create it again by writing to it. The `w` and `wb` modes will truncate an existing file for you. So go from:

```py
if os.path.exists(self._keyFilename):
    os.remove(file)

# skipping code

file = open(self._keyFilename, 'wb')
file.write(key)
file.close()
```

Do this instead:

```py
# get rid of the `if file exists` check

# skipping code
with open(self.key_file_name, 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(key)
```

## Filling a `bytearray`

You have a loop where you fill a `bytearray` with numbers:

```py
for i in range(roll_count):
    transform = bytearray(256)
    for j in range(256):
        transform[j] = j
```

You can skip the other loop and simply have `bytearray` consume the `range`:

```py
for i in range(roll_count):
    transform = bytearray(range(256))
```

## Swapping variables

You can use tuple-style assignment to quickly and easily swap variable values:

```py
# go from this
temp = transform[rand1]
transform[rand1] = transform[rand2]
transform[rand2] = temp

# to this
transform[rand1], transform[rand2] = transform[rand2], transform[rand1]
```

## Generating a list of pseudo-random numbers (no dupes)

You have the following code to do this:

```py
transitions = bytearray()
while len(transitions) < self._transitionCount:
    rand = randint(0, 255)
    if not transitions.count(rand):
        transitions.append(rand)
```

This can be simplified down to

```py
transitions = bytearray(
    random.sample(range(256), transition_count)
)
```

This is much, much faster. `transitions.count(x)` will be O(N), where N is growing for each iteration. Not ideal.

## `is_twisted`

While `0` and `1` can be interpreted as `False` and `True`, respectively through their truthiness, I think it would be better to actually return a boolean here. Also, this could be more succinctly expressed as an `any` statement:

```py
# go from this
def is_twisted(self, trans):
    for i in range(256):
        if trans[i] == i:
            return 0

    return 1

# to this
def is_twisted(self, trans):
    return any(item == i for i, item in enumerate(trans))
```

Where `enumerate` will produce `index`, `item` pairs for each item in an iterable/sequence/generator. Last, you don't actually use `self` here, so `is_twisted` could be a `staticmethod`:

```py
@staticmethod
def is_twisted(trans):
    return any(item == i for i, item in enumerate(trans))
```

## `for`...`else`?

In `Rolls.py`, you have the following snippet:

```py
for i in range(256):
    found = 0
    for j in self._transitions:
        if self._transitions[j] == i:
            found = 1
            continue

    if not found:
        raise ValueError("Transitions not 1-1 complete")
```

This can be reduced down by using an `else` statement on a `for` loop. Yes, there is an `else` for `for`. You can think of it checking to see if a `StopIteration` has occurred:

```py
for i in range(10):
    if i == 5:
        break
else:
    print("Didn't exit early!")


for i in range(10:
    if i == 11:
        break # this won't happen
else:
    print("Didn't exit early!")

Didn't exit early!
```

So your code snippet can reduce down to:

```py
for i in range(256):
    for j in self._transitions:
        if self._transitions[j] == i:
            break
    else:
        # is not found
        raise ValueError("Transitions not 1-1 complete")
```

## Checking Corresponding Elements

Any time you have code comparing corresponding elements of a collection, you can probably use `zip`:

```py
for i in range(len(self._turn_over_indices) - 1):
    if self._turn_over_indices[i] == self._turn_over_indices[i + 1]:
        raise ValueError("turn_over_indices has doubles")
```

Can be turned into:

```py
for left, right in zip(
    self._turn_over_indices[:-1], 
    self._turn_over_indices[1:]
):
    if left == right:
        raise ValueError("doubles!")
```

This could even be cleaned up in your unit tests:

```py
    def init_business_logic(self, transitions, turnovers):
        rolls_encrypt = []
        rolls_decrypt = []

        for index in range(len(transitions)):
            rolls_encrypt.append(Roll(transitions[index], turnovers[index]))
            rolls_decrypt.append(Roll(transitions[index], turnovers[index]))

# can now be
    def init_business_logic(self, transitions, turnovers):
        rolls_encrypt, rolls_decrypt = [], []

        for transition, turnover in zip(transitions, turnovers):
            rolls_encrypt.append(Roll(transition, turnover))
            rolls_decrypt.append(Roll(transition, turnover))
```

## `transform_buffer`

This could be refactored to be more DRY:

```py
    def transform_buffer(self, buffer, mode):
        if mode == Mode.ENC:
            # almost all of this code is repeated except roll.encrypt/decrypt
            for i in range(len(buffer)):
                for roll in self._rolls:
                    roll.encrypt(buffer, i)
                self.roll_on()

        if mode == Mode.DEC:
            for i in range(len(buffer)):
                for roll in self._rolls_reverse:
                    roll.decrypt(buffer, i)
                self.roll_on()
```

The only difference is `roll.encrypt`, `roll.decrypt`, and the direction in which we iterate over `self._rolls`:

```py
    def transform_buffer(self, buffer, mode):
        if mode is Mode.ENC:
              rolls = self._rolls
              func_name = 'encrypt'
        else:
              rolls = self._rolls[::-1]
              func_name = 'decrypt'

        for i in range(len(buffer)):
             for roll in rolls:
                 f = getattr(roll, func_name)
                 f(buffer, i)
             self.roll_on()
```

Speaking of which...

## Reversing iterators

Instead of copying an object and reversing its order, you can just do:

```py
for item in reversed(collection):
    print(item)
```

However, for `transform_buffer`, I used `self._rolls[::-1]` because after the first loop, the `reversed` iterator will be consumed whereas the slice can be reused.

So instead of doing:

```py
class Rolls:
    def __init__(self, rolls):
        self._rolls = rolls
        self._rolls_reverse = rolls.copy()
        self._rolls_reverse.reverse()
```

Just keep one copy of `self._rolls` around.

```py
class Rolls:
    def __init__(self, rolls):
        self._rolls = rolls
        # no reverse copy
```

## `Rolls.roll_on`

I think this method could be named better, since you have two implementations of the `roll_on` function for two different classes. However, `Rolls.roll_on` has a different problem. It's using `bytearray.count` to effectively do a membership test:

```py
def roll_on(self):
    self._position = (self._position + 1) & 0xff
    return self._turn_over_indices.count(self._position)
```

Now, normally with a membership test, I'd recommend a `dict` or `set`, but for this example, I'd just use `in`, since you are either creating a whole new object in memory that you need to keep in sync with the `bytearray` or sacrificing time to check for membership in a 256 element array. I'd choose the latter. However, `bytearray.count` (or any `collection.count`, for that matter) will always iterate through the whole thing. `in` will short-circuit:

```py
def roll_on(self):
    self._position = (self._position + 1) & 0xff
    return self._position in self._turn_over_indices
```

I'll add more items as I find them, but I think this is more than enough to start with.

Comment: Wow, what a lot of advice! I'm really looking forward to implementing this after my holidays... Thx very much!

Comment: Helped me to see what's possible in Python, all points really informative, thx again!